# HighCharts cannot display the loading symbol. Variable is out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

For some reason, I get an error on the showLoading() method stating that it is undefined. I took a closer look at the chrome debugger and it seems that the chart variable is never being initialized. How do I fix this?

I have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



//Stops the submit request
$("#dashBoardRequestForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

//checks for the button click event
$("#submitButton").click(function(e){
    chart = $('#graph1').highcharts();
    console.log("Entered");
    //get the form data and then serialize that
    dataString = $("#dashBoardRequestForm").serialize();

    chart.showLoading();
...Some Ajax Calls and Stuff...
```

The corresponding div in my HTML file is as follows:

```
<div class="container" id="anotherSection" style="max-width : 90%; width: 90%;">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Graphs:</legend>
    <div id="graph1" style="width: 33%; height: 28%; margin : 0; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="graph2" style="width: 33%; height: 28%; margin : 0;float: left;"></div>
    <div id="graph3" style="width: 33%; height: 28%; margin : 0;float: left;"></div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Always use 'var' when declaring/initializing variables. This might be your problem right there.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I made it var chart = instead of just chart =. Still gives the same result.

Comment: Can you recreate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what the problem is. When use click on `#submit-button`, I hope you have already created chart. If not, that's the problem. So this is proper process:

- create chart (using `$("#container").highcharts( { ... } );` - note: options object)
- get chart (using `var chart = $("#container").highcharts();` - note: without options, it's getter)
- now use your variable to show loader: `chart.showLoading()`